# Can't run .sh files in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, scripts, java, minecraft

I used to run minecraft servers in 14.04 by either clicking the .sh file, and selecting run in terminal, or running the .jar file. I'm on 18.04 now, and I can't run the .sh file at all. Double clicking immediately opens up text editor, and dragging it to a terminal also opens the text editor. Trying to open the server.jar gives me a small window for half a second, which immediately closes. Has something changed, and does anyone know how to run .sh files now?

Answer (score 2):

Have you allowed the file to be executed? Try to go to properties and find a checkbox with allow executable, check it. Try executing. This is the graphical way.
For terminal, just drag and drop in a terminal window and add `./` before it (for example: `./install.sh`).